# c++ class inheritance, identifier undefined

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm new to object programming and to c++.

I'm applying what is taught in SoloLearn c++ course about class inheritance.

Class enemy: **enemy.h**

```
class enemy
{
public:
    enemy();
    ~enemy();
    void setAttackPower();
protected:
    int aP;
};
```

**enemy.cpp**:

```
#include "enemy.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enemy::enemy()
    {
        cout << "constructor" << endl;
    }
enemy::~enemy()
    {
        cout << "destructor" << endl;
    }

int aP=0;
void setAttackPower(int a) {
        aP = a;
    }
```

class ninja, that inherits from enemy:
**ninja.h**:

```
#include "enemy.h"

class ninja: public enemy
{
public:
    ninja();
    ~ninja();
    void attack();
};
```

**ninja.cpp**:

```
#include "ninja.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

ninja::ninja()
{
}

ninja::~ninja()
{
}

void attack() {
    cout << "Ninja attack " << aP << endl;
}
```

and the error is:

identifier "aP" is undefined. I can't see the problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You've forgot `enemy::` before `setAttackPower` and `ninja::` before `attack`.

Comment: `void attack()` is not a member of `ninja`.

Comment: @Pete Becker `void attack()` is a public method declared in the header file of ninja. @Alexey Guseynov If I put `enemy::` before `setAttackPower` and `ninja::` before `attack`, Visual Studio signals me errors.

Comment: @simmy - the class `ninja` has a declaration for a public member function named `attack`, but `void attack()` at the end of the snippet named "source"` is not that member function. Change it to `void ninja::attack()`.

Comment: @Pete Becker thank you, it works now. But why I don't need the same with `void setAttackPower(int a) { ` in the file **enemy.cpp** (I edited the name of the files to be more clear)?

Comment: You do need the analogous thing. That function "works" because "enemy.cpp" defines `int aP = 0;`, but that's not the `aP` that's a member of `enemy`.

Answer (score 0):

enemy.cpp
int aP=0; 
You created 2 values with same name: 1st belongs to class and the 2nd is a global value. The compiler cannot deside which one you are trying to use.